# Попытка получить ширину экрана возвращает null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Когда пытался получить ширину экрана мобильного устройства через `Window.Current.Bounds.Width` - результат ошибка `NullReferenceException`.

В чем может быть вообще проблема?

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас приложение плохо задеплоилось. Пробовали удалять приложение, перезапускать эмулятор/переподключать телефон, ребилдить приложение и заливать заново?

Comment: @andreycha В других приложениях все прекрасно работает с этой шириной. Много раз пробовал. Не понимаю в чем проблема вообще.

Comment: Хорошо, а чем отличаются другие приложения? Тип приложений, место вызова этого свойства?

Comment: И еще: попробуйте открыть Exception Settings (Ctrl+Alt+E), поставить галочку всему разделу Common Language Runtime Exceptions и снова запустить в дебаге. Возможно это поможет обнаружить первоначальное исключение.

Comment: @andreycha, огромное тебе спасибо человек, я уже месяца 3 мучался из -за того что у меня не показывались ошибки в опредленном месте в коде. просто вываливалась ошибка и все, сейчас все показывает где и какая, огромное спасибо!

Comment: :) да не за что. У вас есть право закрыть вопрос? Чтоб не болтался неотвеченным.